# Getting undefined result using JSON

Tags: java, jquery, json, dictionary, struts2

I working on a project where I need to use JSON. I am using Struts2, JSON, jQuery.
I am sending httprequest to server like this:-

```
function getBBSJSONData(ths)
{
   //ths is nothing but this pointer
    var id=ths.id;
    var url = 'bbsJsonAction?actionId='+id;

       var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
        url, 
        {
                method: 'post', 
                onComplete: fetchBBSSuccessData
        });   
}
```

Now, I am mapping this request in struts.xml like this

```
 <action name="bbsJsonAction" class="com.x.x.x.BBS_JSON" method="getBBS_json">
            <result type="json"/>
 </action>
```

Now in my action class I am setting JSON object like this

```
public String getBBS_json()
{

    JSONObject jsonObj =null;

        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("actionId", actionId);
        map.put("count", count);

        jsonObj = new JSONObject(map);
        System.out.println(jsonObj);    

   return SUCCESS;
}
```

and finally I am retrieving this JSON result as responseText on client side like this:-

```
function fetchBBSSuccessData(Request){

var d = Request.responseText.evalJSON();

alert(d);                // this shows [object, object]
alert(d.actionId);      //this shows undefined
alert(d.countd);       //this shows undefined
alert(d.jsonData.count);this also shows undefined

}
```

Why  this showing me undefined, How to get the data from this JSON, please suggest me possible changes.

Comment: Try, actionId = d["actionId"]; or some developer tool and check the structure of object you have

Comment: @adil , did wht you said but still getting same result :undefined

Comment: Then check the structure of object in browser developer tool

Comment: {"BBS_json":"success","actionId":6,"bbs_jsonList":null,"jsonObj ":{}} this is wht I am getting in firebug as a response. sorry for mistake alert(d.actionId); shows me 6

Comment: yes, or e.g. in chrome you can have with ctrl+shift+i

Comment: We can't see how your action is defined, hence how it's being serialized, hence what's actually being returned to the client. All we can see is a method-local map, which wouldn't be serialized at all. You need to provide information we can use to help, but right now, it just looks like you're setting method-local references, which are meaningless to the JSON result's serialization.